# Is there a way to dynamically specify a number in a selected range?

Tags: excel

I'm using an Excel table where one column counts how many cells *after* the current row is less in value than the current cell.

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:$B$16,"<"&[@[Set 1]])
```

The problem here is that $B$16 limits me to 16 rows, and this number doesn't change if more rows are added to the bottom of the table. The ideal solution would be to replace the number 16 with something that counts the number of rows in the table column such as:

```
=COUNT(Table2[Set 1])+1
```

This will always return the correct number of rows in the table. However, I don't know of a way to include it into the B3:$B$16 range.

Something like this doesn't work for me:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B&COUNT(Table2[Set 1])+1,"<"&[@[Set 1]])
```

If possible, I would prefer a solution without volatile functions [e.g. INDIRECT() or OFFSET()].

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is there anything in the cells after the range? or are they all blank?

Comment: Nope. The cells after the range are all blank.

Comment: Then My answer will work for you, the first formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is nothing in Column B below the table, you can use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)),"<"&[@[Set 1]])
```

It will always find the last number in Column B.

If there is, than changing your formula with INDEX should work:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:INDEX(B:B,COUNT(Table2[Set 1])+2),"<"&[@[Set 1]])
```

INDEX is not volatile.

Comment: Thanks - both worked for me. Is there a way B:B could be translated into a table reference?

Comment: You can refer to the column by the name but the fact that you need to refer to B3 specically it seems a little long to do it.